# Any example of this kind of algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, model-theory, universal-algebra

Can someone tell me if there is some natural algebraic structure given by an infinite (co)product that has no neutral element ( where a neutral element is one that witnesses $\exists u \forall a [u * a = a = a * u]$), but such that every "finite reduction" (somewhat intuitive, but I could try and come up with something formal if pressed) actually has a (not necessarily unique, not necessarily even 2-sided if you want) neutral element?

I am thinking something like this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra)#Example:_Quinary_sequences

but I cannot see why the infinite product does not have neutral element the (infinite) sequence of all $1$'s, and, furthermore, it seems a bit specific to $5$ arbitrarily, so I would like something more general. Also I don't know what it means when it talks about the supposed "identity/idempotent" element (it seems to switch between sentences) in the relevant "finite reductions" (again, my own terminology) is actually *the* neutral element (with respect to either multiplication or addition in their rng).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right that they chose that ring a bit arbitrarily. It has nothing to do with the property you're interested in.

If you take any infinite collection of nonzero rings (with identity of course) $\{R_i\mid i\in I\}$ then $R=\oplus_{i\in I} R_i$ is a rng without identity, but you can say that it **has local identities**. That is for every $x\in R$, there is an $e\in R$ such that $ex=xe$.

An identity for $R$ would have to be nonzero on every coordinate, and of course no element in that set has that property. So there's no identity.

To answer your first question after having said this, you might be thing of something like a "semigroup with local identities."

Comment: I feel foolish for even asking this, but is $(1,1,...)$ not in $R$?

Comment: @ASillyGuy No, it isn't.

Comment: Ok I think I must be needing sleep or something, but could you give a simple reason as to why $(1,1,...) \notin R$? I can't quickly see it.

Also I think "semigroup with local identities" exactly captures what I want to do, or, more generally a magma if you require all parenthetizations of a given product to respect the identities imposed by having a neutral element.

Comment: @ASillyGuy By definition, the elements of $\oplus R_i$ are the elements of $\prod R_i$ which are finitely nonzero. It sounds like you do not know this.

Comment: Oh ok now it is obvious. No I was briefly under the impression it was just all possible sequences, finitely nonzero or not. This reminds me of the product topology, so something with many more nice properties than just the arbitrary product. Thank you for your patience

Comment: Is there a group equivalent to this, to your knowledge?

Comment: @BigSocks Sorry, it has been a while since I answered this question. Can you explain exactly what "this' you are referring to?

Comment: Certainly. I was wondering if there was a kind of construction/product that would yield a group if continued/taken finitely many times, but instead only gives a semigroup (with inverses) if continued/taken countably many times. This example with rings you don’t have a ring identity for the whole ring, something like $(1_{R_i})$, but you still have the underlying abelian group identity $(0_{R_i})$. So I’m asking if you can do something similar with the latter.

Comment: @BigSocks hm… I can’t think of any. I do not know many exotic forms of products for groups.

Comment: Oh ok, that’s reassuring, in a way, that I am not missing something obvious and that this goal is hard to achieve. So thank you for your input and for thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

**Can someone tell me if there is some natural algebraic structure given by an infinite (co)product that has no neutral element $\ldots$, but such that every "finite reduction" $\ldots$ actually has a $\ldots$ neutral element?**

The first-order sentence $(\exists u)(\forall a)(u*a=a=a*u)$ is preserved by products. This means that if a family of structures satisfies this sentence, then their Cartesian product will also satisfy it. This shows that the answer to the question is No if one uses Cartesian products, at least if each individual factor in the product is considered to be a "finite reduction" of the product.

On the other hand, let $L = \langle \{0\}; \vee,\wedge\rangle$ be the $1$-element lattice in the category of distributive lattices. Define $x*y:=x\wedge y$.
The coproduct $C$ of $\omega$-many copies of $L$ is the $\omega$-generated free
distributive lattice. A neutral element for $*$ would have to be a largest element for $L$. But the infinitely generated free distributive lattice has no largest element, so there is no neutral element for $*$ in $C$. However, every finite distributive lattice has a largest element (= the join of all elements), hence every finite distributive lattice has a neutral element for $*$. Does this mean every "finite reduction" of $C$ has a neutral element for $*$? It depends on the meaning of the quoted phrase, but every finitely generated sublattice of $C$ is finite, and every coproduct of finitely many copies of $L$ is finite, so these types of finite reductions will have a neutral element for $*$.

Comment: Can this be done “constructively”? As in, you start with partial magmas that aren’t not associative at any given stage (so possibly semigroups) and take “symmetrizations” (I have some references for this, but basically you put in inverses (and perhaps an identity element)) where, if you do so finitely often you can complete the symmetrization to a group, but if you do so infinitely often you end up with an inverse semigroup? I have thought about this a bit and this is one of the only places that comes close to considering this idea. If you’d prefer it I could ask another question. Thank you.

Comment: -and the resulting inverse semigroup *lacks an identity element*. (Very important)